# Announcing a Pro Tempore election for 2021

Tags: discussion, election

Earth Science Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/election/1) beginning on **May 24th** to bring in one more moderator.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on May 24, users can [nominate themselves](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the `discussion` and `election` tags.)
- On May 31, if there are two or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-moderator-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-pa), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on June 8.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: Do you mean June 11 for the results?

Comment: Thanks @Jean-MariePrival Fixed that! :)